# SSIS not updating table after insert

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ssis

I have an SSIS package that sends data from SQL 2014 to an Oracle 11G DB. No issues connecting or transferring the data to Oracle but it fails when updating the source SQL tables.     SSIS give ORA-00971:missing SET keyword
Based on the below why would Oracle be looking for a SET keyword?  The update statement is on the SQL database

I've switch connections to reflect the SQL tables (errors resolving the Oracle table names then)

```
 UPDATE    INTERFACE.dbo.TURN
 SET            INTERFACE.dbo.TURN.DUPLICADO = 
 INTERFACE.dbo.TURN.DUPLICADO + 100
 WHERE     EXISTS
                           (SELECT  
    *

 FROM          [REMOTEORA]..[REMOTEORA].[TURN_BALANCE] BO


WHERE      BO.[TURN_BALANCE].[ID_TURN]=INTERFACE.dbo.TURN.N_TURNO AND BO. 
[ID_PLACES] 
= INTERFACE.dbo.TURN.ID_LUGAR AND 

BO.DT_CLOSE =INTERFACE.dbo.TURNO.FIN_TURNO) 
AND (INTERFACE.dbo.TURN.DUPLICADO < 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First changing the connection for the updating piece to the SQL server resolved the ORA error but the updates were still failing and calling TURN_BALANCE a column.  Altering the table alias to four letters (BOYO) vs the two (BO) completely resolved the issue